# Excel macro status bar message reverting to other value

Tags: excel, vba, statusbar

I have the following Excel macro:

```
Sub doe2()
Dim mdate As Date

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

whatrow = 34
mdate = "1/1/2022"

For i = 0 To 5
    For j = 0 To 5
        For k = 0 To 5
            For l = 0 To 5
                For m = 0 To 5
                    Cells(6, 63) = i
                    Cells(7, 63) = j
                    Cells(8, 63) = k
                    Cells(9, 63) = l
                    Cells(10, 63) = m
                    
                    mtotal = Cells(28, 63)
                    
                    Cells(whatrow, 62) = mdate
                    Cells(whatrow, 63) = "z_equiv"
                    Cells(whatrow, 64) = i
                    whatrow = whatrow + 1
                    
                    Cells(whatrow, 62) = mdate
                    Cells(whatrow, 63) = "age"
                    Cells(whatrow, 64) = j
                    whatrow = whatrow + 1
                    
                    Cells(whatrow, 62) = mdate
                    Cells(whatrow, 63) = "last_name"
                    Cells(whatrow, 64) = k
                    whatrow = whatrow + 1
                    
                    Cells(whatrow, 62) = mdate
                    Cells(whatrow, 63) = "first_name"
                    Cells(whatrow, 64) = l
                    whatrow = whatrow + 1
                    
                    Cells(whatrow, 62) = mdate
                    Cells(whatrow, 63) = "city"
                    Cells(whatrow, 64) = m
                    whatrow = whatrow + 1
                    
                    Cells(whatrow, 62) = mdate
                    Cells(whatrow, 63) = "Total"
                    Cells(whatrow, 64) = mtotal
                    whatrow = whatrow + 1
                    
                    mdate = mdate + 1
                    
                    
                       Application.StatusBar = "Record " & whatrow - 33 & " of 3,125"
                    
                Next
            Next
        
        Next
    
    Next
    
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Beep
Beep
Beep

End Sub
```

I am running the program with Automatic Calculations.

When the status bar displays, it flips back and forth between the real value and another value.  When the Visual Basic window was open, it was displaying the number correctly.  But, when I just look at the spreadsheet, I get the strange behavior.

Any explanations?

It is annoying but I see it as a waste of resources as I go through a large spreadsheet.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Write the result to the sheet as a block of 6 by 3 values.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub doe2()

    Dim mdate As Date, n As Long, z As Long, of As String
    Dim whatrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim k As Long, l As Long, m As Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    Dim ar(1 To 6, 1 To 3)
     z = Application.WorksheetFunction.Power(6, 5)
    of = " of " & Format(z, "0,000")
    
    whatrow = 34
    mdate = "1/1/2022"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 0 To 5
        Cells(6, 63) = i
        For j = 0 To 5
            Cells(7, 63) = j
            For k = 0 To 5
                Cells(8, 63) = k
                For l = 0 To 5
                    Cells(9, 63) = l
                    For m = 0 To 5
                        Cells(10, 63) = m
                        
                        ar(1, 1) = mdate
                        ar(1, 2) = "z_equiv"
                        ar(1, 3) = i
                        ar(2, 1) = mdate
                        ar(2, 2) = "age"
                        ar(2, 3) = j
                        ar(3, 1) = mdate
                        ar(3, 2) = "lastname"
                        ar(3, 3) = k
                        ar(4, 1) = mdate
                        ar(4, 2) = "firstname"
                        ar(4, 3) = l
                        ar(5, 1) = mdate
                        ar(5, 2) = "city"
                        ar(5, 3) = m
                        ar(6, 1) = mdate
                        ar(6, 2) = "Total"
                        ar(6, 3) = Cells(28, 63) ' total from cals
                        
                        Cells(whatrow, 63).Resize(UBound(ar), UBound(ar, 2)) = ar
                        whatrow = whatrow + UBound(ar)
                        mdate = mdate + 1
                        
                        n = n + 1
                        Application.StatusBar = "Record " & n & of
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done ", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")

End Sub
```